# How to print pose of a robot using robot_state_publisher

Tags: robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to print the pose of my robot using robot_state_publisher. I am adding the following code in my launch file

> ```
> <include file="$(find
>   p2os_urdf)/launch/upload_pioneer3at.xml"/>  <node pkg="robot_state_publisher"
>   type="state_publisher"
>   name="robot_state_publisher">       <param
>   name="publish_frequency" type="double"
>   value="30.0"/>  </node>
> ```

But, I am not sure, where can I see the pose of the robot? Is there any way I can print it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221252/how-to-print-pose-of-a-robot-using-robot_state_publisher/) by [robo_explorer](https://answers.ros.org/users/24464/robo_explorer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2015-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should create a new node in your workspace, and subscribe to the tf topic, then you can print the values of your coordinates in this new node. I hope this will help you.

---

Originally posted by [Fredylucas](https://answers.ros.org/users/25070/fredylucas/) with karma: 123 on 2015-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robo_explorer](https://answers.ros.org/users/24464/robo_explorer/) on 2015-11-20**:
No, I have Rviz setup, I can see the robot. But I want to see the values of the robot's pose.
For example:  x: 4, y: 5 theta:20

**Comment by [Fredylucas](https://answers.ros.org/users/25070/fredylucas/) on 2015-11-23**:
what about printing the coordinates to console, using ROS_INFO (or something like this) inside the robot_state_publisher node?

**Comment by [robo_explorer](https://answers.ros.org/users/24464/robo_explorer/) on 2015-11-23**:
@Fredylucas That sounds like a good idea to me, but how can I print the values in robot_state_publisher node?

**Comment by [Fredylucas](https://answers.ros.org/users/25070/fredylucas/) on 2015-11-23**:
I take back what I said before, a better way is: you already have the coordinates in the topic published by robot_state_publisher (the topic is tf), you can subscribe to this topic in a new node in your workspace, and print the information in this new node using ROS_INFO.